# How to Convert XML to Json for array elements in java

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, gson

I have a usecase to  convert xml payload to json Payload.I tried with org.json library but it didnot provide me expected output.

Example:
XML

```
<Employees>
<Employee>
<FirstName>abc</FirstName>
<LastName>xyz></LastName>
</Employee>
<Employee>
<FirstName>pqr</FirstName>
<LastName>def></LastName>
</Employee>
</Employees>
```

Expected OutPut:

```
{
Employees:[
{
FirstName:abc,
LastName:xyz
},
{
FirstName:pqr,
LastName:def
}
]
}
```

When i tried with org.json  below is the output.

```
{
Employees:{
Employee:[
{
FirstName:abc,
LastName:xyz
},
{
FirstName:pqr,
LastName:def
}
]
}
}
```

How do i convert XML to expected Json . Is there any other approach where I can use above XML and convert to expected output

Answer (score 2):

The output from the json library looks quite normal to me based on your XML.

Your "expected output" example is actually missing data, there is no reference to employee.

If you want that sort of output you will either need to modify the XML first to remove the `<Employee>` tags maybe using a simple loop, or you could write your own XML parser that ignores the `<Employee>` tags and creates the output you want, but that could be very dangerous.

Try this XML, it should produce something a lot closer to what you want. Note how the `Employee` part has been removed:

```
<root>
    <Employees>
        <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
        <LastName>xyz></LastName>
    </Employees>
    <Employees>
        <FirstName>pqr</FirstName>
        <LastName>def></LastName>
    </Employees>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20201115</version>
</dependency>
```

Could you try this below?

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;
import org.json.JSONException;

public class Main {

    public static int PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR = 4;
    public static String TEST_XML_STRING =
            "<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?><Employees>"
            + "<Employee>"
            + "<FirstName>abc</FirstName>"
            + "<LastName>xyz</LastName>"
            + "</Employee>"
            + "<Employee>"
            + "<FirstName>pqr</FirstName>"
            + "<LastName>def</LastName>"
            + "</Employee>"
            + "</Employees>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            JSONObject xmlJSONObj = XML.toJSONObject(TEST_XML_STRING);
            JSONObject employees = xmlJSONObj.getJSONObject("Employees");

            Object employee = employees.get("Employee");
            xmlJSONObj.put("Employees", employee);
            
            String jsonPrettyPrintString = xmlJSONObj.toString(PRETTY_PRINT_INDENT_FACTOR);
            System.out.println(jsonPrettyPrintString);
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            System.out.println(je.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also may call xmlToJson from underscore-java library.